# How do i get xeditable's content in js

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have below code of xeditable:

```
 $this->widget('editable_ori.Editable', array(   
      'url' => $this->createUrl('index'),
      'pk' => Yii::app()->user->id,
      'name' => 'index',
      'type' => 'text',
      'text' => $data,
      'placement' => 'top',
      'showbuttons' => 'bottom',
      'send' => 'auto',
));
```

I would like to get the content of this field in my js.

I have tried to grab content of this in js using below code. But its not working

```
 $(".editable editable-click").text;
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value in the editable textfield after submit or as soon as it loads?

Comment: @jmsds as soon as it loads.

Comment: do mark the answer as correct which helped you solve the problem. it might help others looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You are missing a `.` before the class name `editable-click`.
- You have an extra space  after the class name `.editable`.
- The method is `text()` in jquery not `text` property to get the text.

Change

```
 $(".editable editable-click").text;
```

to

```
$(".editable.editable-click").text()
```

## `EDIT`

You should call the script after the editable has loaded you can use the event `onInit` to trigger your javascript function from another file which is dependent on the editable input. For instance, if you have a function

```
function myFunction(){
//do something
    $(".editable.editable-click").text()
//do something more
}
```

then you should try calling that function from the `onInit` event like below

```
$this->widget('editable_ori.Editable', array(   
      'url' => $this->createUrl('index'),
      'pk' => Yii::app()->user->id,
      'name' => 'index',
      'type' => 'text',
      'text' => $data,
      'placement' => 'top',
      'showbuttons' => 'bottom',
      'send' => 'auto',
      'onInit' => 'js:function(){myFunction();}'
));
```

Comment: If I use this command in console, it will grab the data. But if I print from my jquery file, its getting empty record.

Comment: @Cristal your file is called before the editable has loaded , how are you loading the js file , update in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onShown` option of editable which will execute as soon as the editable form is shown. You can refer the code below.

```
$this->widget('editable_ori.Editable', array(   
    'url' => $this->createUrl('index'),
    'pk' => Yii::app()->user->id,
    'name' => 'index',
    'type' => 'text',
    'text' => $data,
    'placement' => 'top',
    'showbuttons' => 'bottom',
    'send' => 'auto',
    'onShown' => 'js: function() {
        var txtVal=$(this).data("editable").value;  // This will hold your textbox value as soon as it opens.
        someFunction(txtVal);  //Call your JS function with textbox value as parameter.

    }'
));
```

Then in your JS function, you can do so:

```
<script>
     function someFunction(txtVal)
     {
         //Do anything with editable text box value
     }
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: on show works when you click on the displayed link, he wants to get the content/text as soon as the page loads.